# C: reliably cause `double free or corruption` on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Using `gcc` on Linux, is there a C snippet that is guaranteed to cause a `double free or corruption` error when compiled and executed? (nevermind my reasons for wanting to achieve this). Simply freeing memory obtained via `malloc` multiple times does not always seem to work.

EDIT: the predominant opinion seems to be that I should provide my reasons for wanting to achieve this in the first place. However I would rather not go into those for reasons of my own. The answer seems to be 'no' and that is really all I wanted to hear, I believe that is reasonable.

Comment: Since you most likely invoke undefined behavior, I would say it is not guaranteed to happen.

Comment: There's no guarantee.  Why do you want to do this?  You say "nevermind my reasons" but they are *very* relevant to the question.

Comment: Hard to explain, I want to test error recovery in one of my programs. I guess just calling free() a large number of times should work. What about glibc specific functions or inline assembly?

Comment: Note that GCC has nothing to do with it. Your C library is what prints out the message.

Comment: @Peter Then perhaps you could show an example of your error recovery code that you want to test.  Note also that if your goal is to find real double frees in your code, you should run your code under valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: As I mentioned that is not really relevant, I am not looking for another way to do things, I would just like to know if what I asked is possible, if not I can live with that as well.

Comment: @Peter: You should not try to recover from this type of error. This message indicates that memory has been corrupted, and if memory has been corrupted, nothing is safe. The best you can do is exit the process.

Comment: If you really want to detect and handle this error, your best bet is to use the address sanitizer. You can do this by adding `-fsanitize=address` to the compilation line. This adds a bunch of overhead to your program but checks for many types of errors like this. It does not work 100% but it is certainly going to be better than anything you make yourself.

Comment: I'm not trying to handle the error inside the program in which it occurs, that was maybe formulated poorly. Explaining my whole problem would be too involved, I'm content with the fact that the answer to my question is 'no'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to cause a `double free or corruption` error you have to violate some language rules, which leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Since you can never predict what happens after invoking undefined behavior, there is no guarantee to cause such error.

Comment: I know that is true in general but I somehow doubt that there is no platform specific way to achieve this. If nobody can provide one I guess you're right. I'll wait a while and then accept your answer in that case.

Comment: @Peter I think it also depends on how "reliable" it has to be.

Comment: The fact that the C standard does not define behavior does not mean that other documents do not define the behavior. Linux and GCC have their own specifications and documentation **beyond** the C standard. The C standard cannot say that behavior **must** be undefined by other documents; it can only say that **it** does not define the behavior.